# iOS5 NSMutableDictionary convert to comma separated list of values efficiently

Tags: ios, csv, nsmutabledictionary, stringbuilder, iphone-4

I got ~30000 rows of data in an app that I would like to add to a CSV file and email to the user. Each data point currently has ~20 properties and I'm adding ~20 more values as extended attributes, stored in a NSMutableDictionary. That's a lot of data, and it already takes ~10 seconds to create the file and attach it to an email.

I can build a string of CSV values from regular properties using

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f",prop1,prop2,prop3 ];
```

I can iterate the dictionary like this. I can repeatedly build a string for each key, but this would re-create a new string each time. Is there **an equivalent of StringBuilder or StringBuffer in iOS?**

```
for(NSString *aKey in myDictionary){

    NSLog(aKey);
   //append string

}
```

What's the best way to combine existing properties and extended attributes from an NSMutableDictionary to create a single string of comma separated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize a mutable string outside the for loop and append it however you want.

```
NSMutableString *large_CSV_String = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for(NSString *aKey in myDictionary){

    // Add something from the key?? Your format here.
    [large_CSV_String appendFormat:@",%@",aKey];

}
NSLog(@"%@",large_CSV_String);
```

Comment: and what do you do to remove the first comma which is additional?

Answer (score 3):

This post is old but for anyone looking for a cleaner solution you could do this:

```
NSArray *keys= [myDictionary allKeys];
NSString *csv = [keys componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```